# Not able to call a function with a parameter which is returned from another function in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am calling a function which has switch case statement and it returns a value.
Now I am trying to pass this returned value to a second function in my protractor-cucumber test.

```
When(/^A function is callled$/, function(fields) {
  obj.each(fields.hashes(), function(value) {
    filePath = util.Function_1(value.a, value.b, value.c);
    console.log(filePath);
    response = util.Function_2(filePath);
  });
});
```

Function in Util file:

```
Function_1(a, b, c){
  var num =1;
  switch (num) {
    case "1": {
      var filePath = "dummy path-1 to a file";
      console.log("Inside case-1");
      break;
    }
    case "2": {
      var filePath = "Construct file path using a, b and c";
      console.log("Inside case-2");
      break;
    }
  }
  return filePath;
}
```

Second function:

```
Function_2(filePath){
  console.log("Inside second function");
  //To Do
}
```

I am able to print the value returned from Function_1 in my When section.
But the test is finishing right after printing the returned value.
Its not calling the second function.

I tried creating a promise and returning it from Function_1. 
But couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your variable "num" is actually a number and in the switch case statement you are looking for a string. 
Change your Function_1 as follows and it would work:

```
Function_1(a, b, c){
  var num =1;
  switch (num) {
    case 1: {
      var filePath = "dummy path-1 to a file";
      console.log("Inside case-1");
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      var filePath = "Construct file path using a, b and c";
      console.log("Inside case-2");
      break;
    }
  }
  return filePath;
}
```

Either check for strings with content '1', '2' etc. Or numbers and then check for 1, 2 etc.